# CreateObject call in Application.cfm

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I'm trying to upgrade one application to CF10. Currently the application is running on Codldfusion 6. There is one Create object call in the Application.cfm. It's stopped working after the upgrade. Is there any issue with CreateObject function being used in Application.cfm in version 10? Application.cfm stops functioning whenever there is a CreateObject call in the file.

```
<CFSET obj1= CreateObject("component", "comp1")>
```

Comment: It should not. But there can be many reasons why it has. Does it throw any error? Were any mapping to component were involved which were not carried over by CF upgrade? Any details of "it stopped working", how you reached that analysis that it stopped working will be helpful to trying in helping you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have put debugging comments till the line where this call being made. I'm trying to executed a.cfm, it goes to Application.cfm and execute all the lines till this call and return the control back to a.cfm. That is , the control is going back to normal page instead of continuing the execution of rest of the Applicaiton.cfm. No error is thrown anywhere.

Comment: Nothing is going into any log files? Put debug logging into `comp1.cfc` as well, to determine at which point in its code it stops execution.

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: @John D: Is your cfset example as close to the production code as possible?  Is this a ColdFusion component being used, not a Java or COM object? Does the CreateObject call include a path?